# Flex: setFocus does not work after ENTER on input

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

I want to set the focus on TextInput: This works fine after I press the button, but doers not work when I press the ENTER button on the TextInput: ANY IDEA ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function sendText():void {

                txt_input.enabled = false;
                trace(txt_input.text);
                txt_input.text = "";
                setTimeout(function ():void { 
                    txt_input.enabled = true;
                    focusManager.setFocus(txt_input );
                }
                    ,3000);         
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TextInput id="txt_input" x="173" y="330" enter="sendText()"/>
    <s:Button x="345" y="331" label="Button" click="sendText()"/>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of shifting focus to other component in Ashish's code, replace

focusManager.setFocus(btn); with

stage.focus = null;

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before. I don't exactly know what goes inside the framework but i got my job done by just setting focus to some another component. I know its not the correct way.

In your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            public function sendText():void {

                txt_input.enabled = false;
                focusManager.setFocus(btn);
                trace(txt_input.text);
                txt_input.text = "";
                setTimeout(function ():void { 
                    txt_input.enabled = true;
                    focusManager.setFocus(txt_input );
                }
                    ,3000);         
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:TextInput id="txt_input" x="173" y="330" enter="sendText()"/>
    <s:Button id="btn" x="345" y="331" label="Button" click="sendText()"/>
</s:Application>
```

I think it din't work before is because it has something to do with the "enabled" property.

Hope it helps.